# Excel Spreadsheet tabs

Tags: excel, passwords, spreadsheet

it sounds simple but I am struggling

Do you know how to password protect a single sheet (there’s multiple sheets in the work book) so that you can only view it with a password. So the user can’t see it with the ‘read only’ option, I can only seem to be able to do it to the whole workbook. But just need it for 1 sheet only?

Thanks

Comment: Might not be exactly what you want, but you can always HIDE a tab altogether. Then, no one knows it's there until you right-click on another tab, find "Unhide", and then select to Unhide the hidden tab. Just a suggestion!

Comment: Yeah thought of that but cause it’s linked to a hyperlink it would take you straight to it, I will keep searching though!

Comment: Maybe if you set it to `2 - xlSheetVeryHidden` (in the VBA editor object Properties)?

Comment: Just by typing in that code in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

[image: A visually undiscoverable and password-protected sheet. C4 has test, but you can't see it.]

**A visually undiscoverable and password-protected sheet. C4 has test, but you can't see it. I also removed gridlines for grins.**

I thought about this for a bit, and here's my best answer:

1. Change the cell and font colors to be the same
2. Protect the sheet and disable the ability to change ANYTHING.
3. Hide the sheet, if necessary.

This would force someone to:

1. Have the password.
2. Select All fields on that page, and then change the font color.

If memory serves correctly, this can easily be hacked by importing the workbook to Google Sheets, converting it to a Sheet, and then re-exporting it back to XLSX. In other words, don't be trying to hide anything TOO sensitive here.